# Why does one more Scenario break Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Everything was going fine until I added the SleepWithInterruptHandler `Scenario` to my `Lag.feature` file

```
Feature: Induced Lag
  There are many reasons we might want to induce lag into our code, such as for
  testing, benchmarking, experimenting, etc.

  Scenario: Minimal Duration
    Given a minimal Lag
    When I compute the minimal duration
    Then it should equal zero

  Scenario: Definite Duration
    Given a definite Lag
    When I compute the definite duration
    Then it should equal the minimum duration

  Scenario: Random Duration
    Given a random Lag
    When I compute the random duration
    Then it should not equal either the minimum or the maximum
    And it should not be outside the range

  Scenario: Sleep With Interrupt Handler
    Given a task with random Lag
    When I start it
    Then it should start normally
    And it should complete normally without interrupt
```

While the other scenarios continue to run fine, with the last scenario I get the ***infamous***

```
io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.UndefinedStepException: 
The step 'a task with random Lag' and 3 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:
```

There is nothing at all wrong with my steps class for the scenario, and google search suggests something to do with `glue`, but that does not help. The last scenario fails
under both Maven and IntelliJ.

```
public class SleepWithInterruptHandler implements En {

    Duration minimumDuration = Duration.ofMillis(10);
    Duration maximumDuration = Duration.ofMillis(20);

    Lag randomLag;
    Duration randomDuration;

    AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();
    Lag lag = new Lag(minimumDuration, maximumDuration);
    Runnable withInterruptHandler = new LagTests.WithInterruptHandler(value, lag);
    Thread regularThread = new Thread(withInterruptHandler);

    SleepWithInterruptHandler() {

        Given("a task with random Lag", () -> {
            assertEquals(0, value.get());
        });

        When("I start it", () -> {
            regularThread.start();
        });

        Then("it should start normally", () -> {
            // Wait a little time, but not after our task ends...
            Thread.sleep(minimumDuration.dividedBy(2));
            assertEquals(1, value.get());
        });

        And("it should complete normally without interrupt", () -> {
            // Wait for our task to end...
            regularThread.join();
            assertEquals(3, value.get());
        });
    }
}


public class DefiniteDuration implements En {

    Duration minimumDuration = Duration.ofMillis(10);

    Lag definiteLag;
    Duration definiteDuration;

    public DefiniteDuration() {

        Given("a definite Lag", () -> {
            definiteLag = new Lag(minimumDuration);
        });

        When("I compute the definite duration", () -> {
            definiteDuration = definiteLag.getDuration();
        });

        Then("it should equal the minimum duration", () -> {
            assertEquals(minimumDuration, definiteDuration);
        });
    }
}
```

Full project can be found at https://github.com/kolotyluk/loom-lab

***However, the more important question is, why is Cucumber happy with 3 scenarios but not 4?***

Comment: Heya, I don't think anyone can help you right now. You've not provided enough info to reproduce the problem.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions btw. That's not going to help you debugging.

Comment: Okay, I added some more context. If that is not enough, I can add more. I could be jumping to conclusions, as I am a total Cucumber newbie, and only started using it a couple of days ago.

Comment: Your project isn't minimal so kinda hard to tell. But the difference between the steps for the 3rd and 4th scenario is that the constructor for `SleepWithInterruptHandler` is not public.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was that I forgot to make the constructor of `SleepWithInterruptHandler` public..., so many thanks to M.P. Korstanje for the answer.

Stepping back a bit, this is a common problem I see with some software. ***The diagnostics do not fit the root cause.***

```
io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.UndefinedStepException: 
The step 'a task with random Lag' and 3 other step(s) are undefined.
You can implement these steps using the snippet(s) below:
```

Followed by a bunch of code examples, that when I copy/pasted them... did not work either.

Korstanje was right, I was jumping to conclusions, my conclusion was that the Cucumber diagnostics were telling me something meaningful, when they were not, they were misleading. The other conclusion I jumped to was that Google search would tell me something meaningful, but it largely did not either, because it found a lot of solutions that involved `glue` and there were so many of these search hits, I concluded that the glue problem was ***infamous***, and I concluded that my problem was a glue problem.

Now, there are probably two camps of thought on this

1. That I am some sort of idiot for jumping to conclusions and making a lame
   mistake by not checking that my constructors are public too.
2. That we could and should invests in better diagnostics, that once we
   understand a problem, especially the root cause, we can look for such
   problems, and make that part of the diagnostics, or a least have the
   diagnostics suggest multiple problems with multiple solutions.

As a further example, in the last year I have had to learn Gradle. After more than a decade of using Maven, and then SBT, I have found that Gradle's diagnostics are very immature compared to Maven. I have spent countless hours chasing down Gradle problems because the diagnostics were so very wrong and misleading, and confidently so. SBT... well I won't comment...

Now, I have not tried this in Kotlin or Scala yet, but I should, because in these languages I think the default for constructors is public, which is why I may have forgotten that in Java they are not...

Sorry for the soapbox, but I had an ah-ha moment when I realize the simple problem, and could related it to a larger problem, a larger pattern of how software is designed and implemented, a larger pattern of where I spend my debugging time these days...